# Setup Mock to return the same object, which I send to it?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I want to test some code:

```
public ViewModel FillClientCreateViewModel(ViewModel model){
    model.Phone = new Phone { Name = "Test"};

    model.Phone = _entityInitializer.FillViewModel(model.Phone);
}
```

I also want to setup FillViewModel to return the same object as I give to it.

My test:

```
     entityInitMock.Setup(x => x.FillViewModel(It.IsAny<PhoneViewModel>())).Returns(It.IsAny<PhoneViewModel>());

 var result = TestedInstance.FillClientCreateViewModel(CreateViewModel);

 result.Phone.Name.ShouldBe("Test");
```

But in this case my test fell - because result.Phone.Name was cleaned by my mock.

How can I setup mock to just give me the same object which i give to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
entityInitMock.Setup(x => x.FillViewModel(It.IsAny<PhoneViewModel>()))
    .Returns((PhoneViewModel m) => m);
```

The [Moq QuickStart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) is a great reference for similar questions.

Comment: how do you make that work in ReturnsAsync ? I get "Cannot convert lambda expression to type ___ because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: @johni See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527394/moq-returnsasync-with-parameters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253523/setup-async-task-callback-in-moq-framework

Comment: Good answer. Such nuances in TDD scenarios are important to cover to get all the nuts and bolts in place for detailed TDD. Thanks.