# How can I tell Moq to return a Task?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, moq

I've got an interface which declares

```
Task DoSomethingAsync();
```

I'm using MoqFramework for my tests:

```
[TestMethod()]
public async Task MyAsyncTest()
{
   Mock<ISomeInterface> mock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
   mock.Setup(arg => arg.DoSomethingAsync()).Callback(() => { <my code here> });
   ...
}
```

Then in my test I execute the code which invokes `await DoSomethingAsync()`. And the test just fails on that line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say the test errors on that line, what error does it produce?

Comment: @AlSki propably a NullReferenceException. as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882817/nullreferenceexception-in-unittest-using-verifyable-on-an-async-method)

Answer (score 933, accepted):

Your method doesn't have any callbacks so there is no reason to use `.CallBack()`. You can simply return a Task with the desired values using `.Returns()` and [Task.FromResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
MyType someValue=...;
mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync())        
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(someValue));
```

**Update 2014-06-22**

Moq 4.2 has two new extension methods to assist with this.

```
mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(someValue);

mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync())        
    .ThrowsAsync(new InvalidOperationException());
```

**Update 2016-05-05**

As Seth Flowers mentions in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33745050/444610), `ReturnsAsync` is only available for methods that return a `Task<T>`. For methods that return only a Task,

```
.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)))
```

can be used.

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27294996/134204), in .NET 4.6 this is simplified to `.Returns(Task.CompletedTask);`, e.g.:

```
mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync())        
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);  that was my answer

Comment: Thank you for keeping this answer up-to-date as the Moq framework has received updates!

Comment: `.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object))` works well when the return type is void.  `.Returns(Task.FromResult(null as MyType))` works well when the expected return type is null.

Comment: @JeremyRayBrown as I explain, in .NET 4.6 `default(object)` is no longer needed. `null as MyType` is the same as `default(MyType)` as long as `MyType` is a reference type.

Comment: now in .net and Mock supports ReturnAsync and directly return your object. without Task.CompletedTask or FromResult

Answer (score 44):

**Similar Issue**

I have an interface that looked roughly like:

```
Task DoSomething(int arg);
```

**Symptoms**

My unit test failed when my service under test `awaited` the call to `DoSomething`.

**Fix**

Unlike the accepted answer, you are unable to call `.ReturnsAsync()` on your `Setup()` of this method in this scenario, because the method returns the non-generic `Task`, rather than `Task<T>`.

However, you are still able to use `.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)))` on the setup, allowing the test to pass.

Comment: Just a thought on this, if you need to return a non-generic task (non .net 4.6), I would consider returning Task.Delay(1) as an easy way to return a Task.  You can also mimic work too by increasing the time argument.

Answer (score 30):

You only need to add `.Returns(Task.FromResult(0));` after the Callback.

Example:

```
mock.Setup(arg => arg.DoSomethingAsync())
    .Callback(() => { <my code here> })
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(0));
```

Answer (score 4):

Now you can also use Talentsoft.Moq.SetupAsync package
https://github.com/TalentSoft/Moq.SetupAsync

Which on the base on the answers found here and ideas proposed to Moq but still not yet implemented here: https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/384, greatly simplify setup of async methods

Few examples found in previous responses done with SetupAsync extension:

```
mock.SetupAsync(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync());
mock.SetupAsync(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync()).Callback(() => { <my code here> });
mock.SetupAsync(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync()).Throws(new InvalidOperationException());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the accepted answer for a very helpful solution.

I have added two extension methods (for `Task` and `ValueTask`) to our projects to make it more discoverable for people used to calling `.ReturnsAsync` on all async setups.

```
public static class MoqExtensions
{
    public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock>(this IReturns<TMock, Task> mock)
        where TMock : class
    {
        return mock.Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock>(this IReturns<TMock, ValueTask> mock) 
        where TMock : class
    {
        return mock.Returns(ValueTask.CompletedTask);
    }
}
```

It can be called as follows:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomethingAsync())        
    .ReturnsAsync();
```