# how to moq a func parameter when unit testing c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write some tests but I'm not sure how to handle the arguments for setting up my moq mock.  Can anyone suggest how I can complete this line of code correctly?
Many thanks,

**My moq code line**

[image]

The parameter is of type shown below for the Returns(...) which I'm not sure how to handle.

**Parameter intellisense**

[image]

The method is shown below that I'm trying to moq out.

**The method definition**

```
public static async Task<CommandResult> SendSupportAsync(this IBus bus, Command command, bool withLogging = true)
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried the suggestion, I've added the mocked object and set up the return but the compiler gives the following error:

```
An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments
```

Comment: I did not know MOQ mocked out static methods. I thought you would have to get a testing tool such as TypedMock or the one from Telerik.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock the return value, then you can create a mock for it

```
var resultMock = new Mock<Task<CommandResult>>();
```

then setup your mock object, and you return it like

```
bus.Setup(x=>c.SendSupportAsync(new TagCommand(ID, MID))).Returns(resultMock.object);
```

If you do not want to mock the result, then you can create an instance and return it like

```
bus.Setup(x=>c.SendSupportAsync(new TagCommand(ID, MID))).Returns(objCommandResult);
```

Comment: For your case since you are returning async Task, Moq 4.2 added a ReturnsAsync() extension method. But I have no experience using it.

Comment: Here is a related thread that discusses on returning async task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253523/setup-async-task-callback-in-moq-framework

Comment: thanks Suresh, I've updated the question, I get a compiler error