# Moq ReturnsAsync() with no parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I use Moq. I have mocked a class which has method that looks like following:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    // do something...
}
```

I setup it like below:

```
SomeMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething())
                .Callback(() => ... ))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(default(int)));
```

I don't like last line: `.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(int)))`. Is there a way to setup async return in more elegant way. I know there is a method `ReturnsAsync()` but it has a parameter. My method returns just `Task` so I don't have a parameter for `ReturnsAsync()`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
someMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething())
   .Callback(() => {})
   .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Note that `Task.CompletedTask` only exists in .NET 4.6 (which was released very recently) or newer. You can find more information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244114/create-a-completed-task) StackOverflow answer.

`ReturnsAsync` is for use when you are returning a value asynchronously. When you are returning just a `Task`, you are not actually returning any asynchronous value at all, so `ReturnsAsync` doesn't really 'fit' here.

If this doesn't suit your needs, you will have to use `Task.FromResult()`, unfortunately. As far as I know this is really the only way to create a 'completed' task - <s>aside from perhaps `new Task(() => {})` (although this isn't really a completed task, more than a task that completes instantly when awaited)</s> `new Task(() => {})` causes a deadlock. Use `Task.Run(() => {})`.

Comment: Actually, awaiting `new Task(() => {})` would lead to a deadlock, since that task hasn't and never will be started. `Task.Run(() => {})` would work though. That being said, I still prefer `Task.FromResult` when using .NET 4.5.

Comment: Another alternative I found is using .Returns(Task.Delay(1)). It also works for me.

Comment: It also appears to work with `Task.FromResult<object>(null)`.