# NullReferenceException in UnitTest using Verifyable on an async Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, moq, xunit

I just had a problem with setting up a Unit Test using `xUnit` and `Moq`.

#### My Testee

The Method `TestMethod()` contains the Logic, I want to test. It is async and though returns a `Task`

```
public class Testee
{
    private readonly IDoSomething _doSomething;

    public Testee(IDoSomething doSomething)
    {
        _doSomething = doSomething;
    }

    public async Task TestMethod()
    {
        await _doSomething.DoAsync(true); // throws NullReferenceException in Unit-Test
    }
}
```

The Interface `IDoSomething` looks like this

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    Task DoAsync(bool aboolean);
}
```

#### The Unit-Test

Now im Setting up my Unit-Test like this.

```
public class TesteeTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IDoSomething>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.DoAsync(It.IsAny<bool>())).Verifiable();

        var testee = new Testee(mock.Object);

        await testee.TestMethod(); // Test breaks here because it throws an exception

        mock.Verify(x => x.DoAsync(true), Times.Once);
        mock.Verify(x => x.DoAsync(false), Times.Never);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Comment: I feel although it's not an exact duplicate, it's as close as could be for the given scenario.. I don't think it's useful to have this question when the dupe target covers a lot of the required code and the NullReferenceException canonical exists

Comment: I agree on the similarity, the difference is indeed that the suggested duplicate was missing the *Task completion*, while my question was missing the Task at all. This makes it different, because ususally, you would use `.ReturnsAsync?` to return something asynchronous, which wasn't an option, as you cannot call `ReturnsAsinc` with `void`.

Comment: @everyone As I've also marked this question as duplicate, I clearly agree with the similarity. However I don't get the reason of the downvote on this question. If someone might take the time to help me understand how to better write such a question next time.

Comment: I think it's an excellent question. The other questions are "how to". This one's "why null reference". I changed a method returning void to being tested from asynchronous returning Task and all my unit tests broke because I didn't do this setup

Answer (score 4):

The `mock.Setup()` is missing a return value and returns `null`. So in the `TestMethod()` the `Task` returned by `_doSomething.DoAsync(true)` is `null`. `null` gets awaited which of course results in a `System.NullReferneceException`.

To Fix this, I'd recommend adding `.Returns(Task.CompletedTask)` to the Mock-Setup.

```
mock.Setup(x => x.DoAsync(It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
```

As `await` gets compiled using the Awaiter-Pattern, there's now a Task to call `.GetAwaiter()` on it, to return a `TaskAwaiter`. These principles are better explained here:

- [dixin's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern)
- [Marko Papic's Blog](https://www.markopapic.com/csharp-under-the-hood-async-await/)