# Moq ReturnsAsync() with parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock a repository's method like that

```
public async Task<WhitelistItem> GetByTypeValue(WhitelistType type, string value)
```

using Moq ReturnsAsync, like this:

```
static List<WhitelistItem> whitelist = new List<WhitelistItem>();

var whitelistRepositoryMock = new Mock<IWhitelistRepository>();

whitelistRepositoryMock.Setup(w => w.GetByTypeValue(It.IsAny<WhitelistType>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                                    .ReturnsAsync((WhitelistType type, string value) =>
                                    {
                                        return (from  item in whitelist
                                                where item.Type == type && item.Value == value
                                                select item).FirstOrDefault();
                                    });
```

but i'm getting this error in the line "... ReturnsAsync((WhitelistType type...):

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Model.WhitelistItem' because
>   it is not a delegate type

WhitelistType is an Enum like that:

```
public enum WhitelistType
    {
        UserName,
        PostalCode
    }
```

I searched by hours and didn't found any answer to my problem.

Any clues?

Answer (score 99):

### From **Moq v4.5.28 onwards**

You can use `ReturnsAsync` with lambdas, exactly as in the code example of the question. No need to use `Task.FromResult()` any more. You just **need** to specify the types of the lambda delegate arguments. Otherwise you will get the same error message:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Model.WhitelistItem' because it is not a delegate type

To give an example, the following works with the latest version of Moq:

```
whitelistRepositoryMock.Setup(w => w.GetByTypeValue(It.IsAny<WhitelistType>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                                .ReturnsAsync((WhitelistType type, string value) =>
                                {
                                    return (from  item in whitelist
                                            where item.Type == type && item.Value == value
                                            select item).FirstOrDefault();
                                });
```

---

### **Before Moq v4.5.28 (answer provided by [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov))**

You have to use `Returns` with `Task.FromResult`:

```
.Returns((WhitelistType type, string value) =>
 {
     return Task.FromResult(
       (from  item in whitelist
           where item.Type == type && item.Value == value
           select item).FirstOrDefault()
       );
});
```

Comment: How come this works for you?
I get "Cannot convert lambda expression to type x because it is not a delegate type" even after specifying the type and doing it exactly like you. Latest Moq 4.14 or something

Comment: I've just been doing this:

`mock.Setup(o => o.MethodAsync(ArgType arg)).Returns<ArgType>(async arg => { var someResult = await SomeOtherAsync(arg); return someResult; });`
Seems to work just fine. No need for either `Task.FromResult` or `ReturnsAsync`.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is an old question, but the one answer given here did not work for me and I was able to figure it out. It seems that you have to include the mocked function's argument types as type parameters to `ReturnsAsync()` *first*, followed by the mocked class type, and then the return type.

For example: `.ReturnsAsync<T1, T2, TMock, TResult>((arg1, arg2) => { ... } )`

Where `T1, T2` are the types of your mocked function's arguments, and `(arg1, arg2)` are the actual arguments given when the mock was called.

So given the code from the OP, it would look like this:

```cs
whitelistRepositoryMock.Setup(w => w.GetByTypeValue(It.IsAny<WhitelistType>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                       .ReturnsAsync<WhitelistType, string, IWhiteListRepository, WhitelistItem>((type, value) =>
                       {
                            return (from  item in whitelist
                                    where item.Type == type && item.Value == value
                                    select item).FirstOrDefault();
                       });
```

*Edit: I realized later in the previous answer that the types are given in the lambda which does work. If you leave out the types, like I did, it will not. You would have to use the form I used.*

Comment: Your "Edit" part saved me! Tnx

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<int?, int?, Ret>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Func<int?, int?, Ret>'. ` If I wrap last generic in ReturnsAsync with Task instead I get `ISetup<IClient, Task<Ret>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'GeneratedReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<int?, int?, IClient, Task<Ret>>(IReturns<IClient, Task<Task<Ret>>>, Func<int?, int?, Task<Ret>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IReturns<IClient, Task<Task<Ret>>>