# How to return passed parameters in an async method with Moq in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-core

I am struggling with the problem of how to use the Moq-Setup-Return construct.

First, my setting:

Some repository of type `IRepository`-Interface has to implement the `StoreAsync`-Method that returns a StoreResult object with the stored entity as property included.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Entity { }

    public class StoreResult
    {
        public Entity Entity { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        Task<StoreResult> StoreAsync(Entity entity);
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            var moq = new Mock<IRepository>();
            moq.Setup(m => m.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<Entity>())).Returns(e => Task.FromResult<Task<StoreResult>>(new StoreResult {Entity = e}));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try to write a Mock-Objekt for the IRepository-Interface, but I do not know how to code the Return-Statement so that the StoreResult-Object includes the entity given as a parameter to the StoreAsync-Function.

I read about this topic in [Moq ReturnsAsync() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527394/moq-returnsasync-with-parameters) and [Returning value that was passed into a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996602/moq-returning-value-that-was-passed-into-a-method).

I have tried

```cs
moq.Setup(m => m.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
     .ReturnsAsync(entity => new StoreResult {Entity = entity});
```

with the error statement "Cannot convert lambda expression to type "`StoreResult`", because it is not a delegate type.

And with the same error message I tried

```cs
moq.Setup(m => m.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
     .Returns(e => Task.FromResult<Task<StoreResult>>(new StoreResult {Entity = e}));
```

I am using a .NET Core xUnit environment with `Moq 4.6.36-alpha`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be: `Task.FromResult<StoreResult>(new StoreResult {Entity = e})`

Comment: @CallumLinington - With `.Returns(Task.FromResult<StoreResult>(new StoreResult {Entity = e}));` e is not defined.

Comment: That is what `It.IsAny` does. Give it a proper entity!!!

Comment: @CallumLinington  Aaah, I see. `moq.Setup(m => m.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<Entity>())).Returns((Entity e) => Task.FromResult(new StoreResult {Entity = e}));` did the trick.

Comment: Yeah, you need to specify the object always, because of the amount of overloads, there are ambiguous calls

Comment: @rboe Did you totally solve this one?

Comment: @NateBarbettini - Oh yes, this solved the issue. For the records I added the information as answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from Callum Linigton I came to the following solution:

```
moq
 .Setup(m => m.StoreAsync(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
 .Returns((Entity e) => Task.FromResult(new StoreResult {Entity = e}));
```

The key difference is to specify the type for the input parameter of the lambda expression in order to avoid ambiguous calls.