# Moq ReturnsAsync cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Foo' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, moq

I'm trying to setup a mock return that returns the parameter passed into it.

The method signature that I'm trying to mock:

```
public async Task<Foo> SendFoo(Foo foo)
```

How I'm trying to mock it:

```
var mock = new Mock<FooClient>();
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.SendFoo(It.IsAny<Foo>())).ReturnsAsync<Foo>(foo => Task.FromResult(foo));
```

I'm receiving the error message that "**cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Foo' because it is not a delegate type**".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moq ReturnsAsync() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527394/moq-returnsasync-with-parameters)

Comment: The question I linked above will actually only work if you use `.Setup()` and not `.SetupSequnce()`. It doesn't look like an API exists for this functionality when using `.SetupSequence()`, but a PR is currently open in GitHub to add that: https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/573